# KMP-NativeCoroutines do not create asyncFunction/asyncResult methods for iOS

Tags: ios, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I've added KMP-NativeCoroutines lib to my project. I'm able to get initial flow (marked @NativeCoroutinesState) value.
But when I try to call suspend function or subscribe to a flow, for example:

```
let handle = Task {
            do {
                let data = try await asyncFunction(for: service.getData())
                print("Got data: \(data)")
            } catch {
                print("Failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

I receive an error

*Cannot find 'asyncFunction' in scope*

Same with asyncSequence and asyncResult.

Answer (score 1):

Swift part of KMP-NativeCoroutines is missing, be sure:

1. You installed library using [CocoaPods](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines#swift-cocoapods) or [SPM](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines#swift-swift-package-manager)

For SPM, add to `Package.swift`:

```swift
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines.git", from: "<version>")
]
```

For CocoaPods add to your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'KMPNativeCoroutinesAsync', '<version>'    # version of kotlin-coroutine you are using
```

2. You have imported `import KMPNativeCoroutinesAsync`
3. Take a look at library [samples](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines/tree/master/sample)

Comment: I've added all these. After some rebuilds/reboot asyncFunction appeared, but now I have a different error even after coping all the code from the sample: 
Cannot convert value of type '(@escaping (String, KotlinUnit) -> KotlinUnit, @ escaping (any Error, KotlinUnit) -> KotlinUnit, @ escaping (any Error, KotlinUnit) -> KotlinUnit) -> () -> KotlinUnit' to expected argument type '(@ escaping (String, KotlinUnit) -> KotlinUnit, @ escaping (any Error, KotlinUnit) -> KotlinUnit) -> () -> KotlinUnit'

Comment: Now it looks like problem in Kotlin code inside KMM shared module. Take a look at generated Objective-C API, double check that you are using compatible versions of kotlin-coroutines/KMP-NativeCoroutines everywhere

Comment: id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9"
id("com.rickclephas.kmp.nativecoroutines") version "1.0.0-ALPHA-5"
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")

kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10"
kotlin("android").version("1.8.10").apply(false)
kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.8.10").apply(false)


Also tried: 
1.8.20-1.0.10 with 1.0.0-ALPHA-6 and 1.8.20 for kotlin

Same error in both cases...

Answer (score 0):

2 Possible problems to resolve all the dependencies:

- Manually select version when adding package to iOS project (https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines.git)
- Ktorfit was implemented before. For a fresh project - works OK, for my current project before Ktorfit implementation - works OK. Unable to add Ktorfit after adding KMP-NativeCoroutines (continue playing with the versions).